# SqlParameter not working with INSERT statement

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am getting the following error when trying to use a parameter to insert a value into my SQL Server database.

```
SqlParameter Param1 = new SqlParameter("@test", SqlDbType.VarChar);
Param1.Value = "test";

SqlCommand AddtoDb = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [temp] VALUES (@test)", conn);
AddtoDb.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is the error I get:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

The database has only 1 column that accepts `varChar(50)`. I know the connection is working because the database received the input if I do something like:

```
SqlCommand AddtoDb = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [temp] VALUES ('test')", conn);
AddtoDb.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the fill error text, when the execption shows up in the debugger click the [Copy To Clipbord](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/saraford/WindowsLiveWriter/Didyouknowyoucancopytheexceptiondetailsw_F67C/image_2.png) link then paste the text here inside a set of `<pre></pre>` tags. You have left out the details that would give us any chance of figuring out what went wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You created the parameter, but you haven't actually associated it with the command in any way. You need to add the parameter to the command's `Parameters` collection:

```
SqlCommand AddtoDb = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [temp] VALUES (@test)", conn);
SqlParameter Param1 = new SqlParameter("@test", SqlDbType.VarChar);
Param1.Value = "test";
AddtoDb.Parameters.Add(Param1);
AddtoDb.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Or more simply:

```
SqlCommand AddtoDb = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [temp] VALUES (@test)", conn);
AddtoDb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", "test");
AddtoDb.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: just a simple perhaps retorical question, but shouldn't the `@` be left out for the name? I taught it was added automatically.

Comment: @Silvermind No. It should be included. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.parametername.aspx): "*The ParameterName is specified in the form `@paramname`. You must set ParameterName before executing a SqlCommand that relies on parameters.*"

Answer (score 2):

You aren't associating your SqlParameter object with the SqlCommand object.

Try adding this line between lines 3 and 4:

```
AddtoDb.Parameters.Add(Param1);
```